# How do I extend the current theme to my components in expo react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native, styles, darkmode

I'm trying to implement themes (dark | light) in my expo react-native app. I've been reading their [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/guides/color-schemes/#detecting-the-color-scheme) on the dark and light themes on the expo page, and that works inside App.js. However, whenever I declare a component and import it in App.js, it won't work. My thought process is trying to "extend" the current theme to my component.

Here's the App.js code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, useColorScheme } from 'react-native';

//import firebase + config
import firebaseConfig from './config'
import firebase from 'firebase'

//initialize firebase application
if(!firebase.apps.length){
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
} else{
  firebase.app()
}

//import screens
import Overview from './screens/Overview'

export default function App() {
  
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  const themeTextStyle = colorScheme === 'light' ? styles.lightThemeText : styles.darkThemeText;
  const themeContainerStyle = colorScheme === 'light' ? styles.lightContainer : styles.darkContainer;
  
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, themeContainerStyle]}>
        <Overview />
      </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  lightContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  darkContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#101010',
  },
  lightThemeText: {
    color: '#000000',
  },
  darkThemeText: {
    color: '#ffffff',
  },
});
```

And here's my simple component:

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text, useColorScheme} from 'react-native'

export default class App extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>OverView</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

All I'm trying to do is get that **Overview** component to follow the theme rules instead of needing to declare the style that's already been declared in **App.js**.

Now it's not reflected in the code, but I did try a lot of stuff before posting this question.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately, ReactNative doesn't do that magically, so you need to define component styles each time you declare them.
I personally prefer creating some shared components and define the base theme there. You can follow 'atomic-design' principles to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, install `react-native-appearance` from [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/appearance/)

Create a folder called `context` where your `App.js` is located then inside it create a file called `ThemeContext.js` inside which will look like this

```
import React from "react";

const ThemeContext = React.createContext();

export default ThemeContext;
```

Then your `App.js` should look like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { AppearanceProvider, useColorScheme } from 'react-native-appearance';

//import firebase + config
import firebaseConfig from './config';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import ThemeContext from './context/ThemeContext'; // Imported Here

//initialize firebase application
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  firebase.app();
}

//import screens
import Overview from './screens/Overview';

export default function App() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  const themeValue =
    colorScheme === 'light' ? styles.lightThemeText : styles.darkThemeText;
  const themeContainerStyle =
    colorScheme === 'light' ? styles.lightContainer : styles.darkContainer;

  return (
    <AppearanceProvider>
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={themeValue}> // Wrapped Here
        <View style={[styles.container, themeContainerStyle]}>
          <Overview />
        </View>
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    </AppearanceProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  lightContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  darkContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#101010',
  },
  lightThemeText: {
    color: '#000000',
  },
  darkThemeText: {
    color: '#ffffff',
  },
});
```

Your `Overview.js` should look like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import ThemeContext from '../context/ThemeContext';

function Overview() {
  const themeContext = React.useContext(ThemeContext);

  console.log(themeContext); // You will get styles logged into the console here

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>OverView</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default Overview;
```

Comment: Seems promising, I'll be sure to try it, thanks alot!